# Updating the Security

Tags: upgrade

I received a notification to update my security but am unsure on how to do this. I've went to my notifications and it didn't say how to proceed. I also looked in my menu options. I'm honestly lost.

Comment: There is currently no way to do a CiviCRM update via the user interface. If you cannot perform the rather techniocal process of the update (linked in Philippe's Answer) you should ask your IT service provider or your hoster to support you.

Comment: What CMS are you using? What is the specific notification your are getting? There are different types of security notifications. The most common seems to be the need to update CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you do this yourself or not will depend on how you are being hosted. If this is not a site that you set up, and don't have technical experience you probably need to talk to your IT support or hosting agency.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in this news : https://civicrm.org/blog/dev-team/security-release-civicrm-4726-and-4633-monthly-release-4727

Look at the paragraph "Upgrading to 4.7" to find the link to the documentation for the update.